# How to send Chinese characters from SAP to PHP through RFC?

Tags: php, saprfc, function-module

i am communicating to PHP through RFC using function module.i tried to send chinese characters from function module to PHP , but in PHP side i am getting chinese charcters in the form of ###### ,

i don't understand which side the problem is  ,either PHP side or SAP side?
anyone give me suggestion which side do i need to focus to rectify this problem ? or any other way to send chinese character to PHP?

SAP FM Code:FN Name: ZMM_PHP_TO_SAP

```
     t_log-msgty = 'E'.
    CONCATENATE p_uname '用户无检料权限' INTO t_log-msgtx SEPARATED BY space.
    APPEND t_log.
```

PHP Code:

```
 $LOGIN = array ("ASHOST"=>$row_login1["sap_server"],
            "SYSNR"=>$row_login1["sap_system_number"],
            "CLIENT"=>$row_login1["sap_client"],
            "USER"=>$row_login1["sap_username"],
            "PASSWD"=>$row_login1["sap_password"],
            "CODEPAGE"=>"8300");

$rfc = saprfc_open ($LOGIN);

if(!$rfc){
$error=saprfc_error();
return "The RFC connection has failed with the following error:".saprfc_error();
exit;}
$fce = saprfc_function_discover($rfc,"ZMM_PHP_TO_SAP");
if(!$fce){
    return "The function module has failed.";
    return $rfc;
    exit;}saprfc_import ($fce,"P_UNAME","demo-china");
saprfc_table_init ($fce,"T_LOG");

// Call and execute the function
$rc = saprfc_call_and_receive ($fce);
if ($rfc_rc != SAPRFC_OK){
    if ($rfc == SAPRFC_EXCEPTION ){
        echo ("Exception raised: ".saprfc_exception($fce));
    } else {
        echo ("Call error: ".saprfc_error($fce));
    }
    echo "failure";
    exit;
}
$data_row = saprfc_table_rows ($fce,"T_LOG");
    $log_msg='';
    if($data_row != 0 || $data_row != '')   
    {
        for ($i=1; $i<=$data_row; $i++)
        {
        $DATA = saprfc_table_read ($fce,"T_LOG",$i);
        echo $DATA['MSGTX'];
            if($DATA['MSGTY'] == "E")
            {
            $log_msg =$DATA['MSGTX'];
            }
            if($DATA['MSGNO'] == "D")
            {
            $log_msg ="D";

            }

        }
    }
```

when itry to print $DATA['MSGTX'] the output is DEMO-CHINA ¥Î###®Æ#­­ , how to get exact Chinese characters.
thanks in advance.

Comment: What function module do you use? What PHP server do you use?

Comment: SAP Function Module , which is connecting through RFC connection , and i am using Apache server.

Comment: You mean you call some remote-enabled FM from outside (from Apache environment)? What function module do you call? Is it Z-module or standard? Can you name it?

Comment: yes, i am calling remote enabled FM from SAP using Apache server , yes its Z-Module.ex , ZMM_SEND_TO_PHP ,which is created in SAP.

Comment: We cannot help you unless we get code of your Z-module

Comment: @Suncatcher in function module i am directly sending chinese characters via table , when i receive those chinese characters which is not coming in correct format.

Comment: Are we telepathists? How can we imagine what do you do in your FM. It is senseless conversation without code.

Comment: @Suncatcher , sorry about that , can u please help me now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found answer finally.

```
$LOGIN = array ("ASHOST"=>$row_login1["sap_server"],
        "SYSNR"=>$row_login1["sap_system_number"],
        "CLIENT"=>$row_login1["sap_client"],
        "USER"=>$row_login1["sap_username"],
        "PASSWD"=>$row_login1["sap_password"],
        "CODEPAGE"=>"4110");
```

CODEPAGE from 8300 to 4110 solves my issue

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should **never** hardcode character characters/strings in any programming language and particularly in ABAP. In most cases SAP systems are multilingual systems, which are utulized internationally, therefore symbols hardcoded in one environment could be interpreted differently in another environment. Under term *environment* I mean logon language, user parameters and et cetera. 

Hence we don't know exactly the way how literals will be treated during call of your FM, possible steps we can make in this case are following:

1. First and foremost, convert your literal in `CONCATENATE` statement into [text-symbol](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nwpi71/helpdata/en/e3/960a0eeb0711d194d100a0c94260a5/content.htm). Text symbols is a recommended way storing character strings in ABAP.
2. Then I recommend you to check whether your SAP system is Unicode. This can be done via *System > Status > Unicode system* menu. It is highly unlikely that your system is non-Unicode but, nevertheless, this check is strongly appreciated.
3. **[Optional]** This step is optional and makes sense only if your system is non-Unicode, nevertheless, it would be useful anyway. Set your environment codepage into Chinese by statement

   ```
   SET LOCALE LANGUAGE 1.
   ```

   Put the statement into the start fo the FM.
4. Also it will be sensible to ensure that Unicode system checks are enabled in your function module. To so this you should go to *Go to > Main program > Go to > Attributes* and make sure that *Unicode checks active checkbox* is active.

Comment: as you said i have followed your steps , but still i am getting the same , in sap side i am getting proper output. but in PHP side its not working.